# No Extension Exists for pmml:predict WSO2 Stream Processor

Tags: maven, wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am following the WSO2 Stream Processor Studio tutorials to practice Siddhi. So far I've managed to troubleshoot all the bugs incorporated in the tutorials; however, I'm stuck on the 12th tutorial, "Making Real-Time Predictions."

The Siddhi application is

```
@App:name("SugarSyrupPredictionApp")
@app:description("Making real-time predictions tutorial 12")

@source(type='http', receiver.url='http://localhost:5006/SugarSyrupEP', @map(type = 'json'))
define stream SugarSyrupDataStream (temperature double, density double);

@sink(type='log', prefix='Predicted next sugar syrup shipment:')
define stream PredictedSugarSyrupDataStream (nextTemperature double, nextDensity double, decision bool);

from SugarSyrupDataStream#pmml:predict('/data/wso2sp-4.0.0-beta3/wso2/lib/features/siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml-4.0.0/component/src/test/resources', temperature, density)
select * 
insert into PredictedSugarSyrupDataStream;
```

At the line starting with from SugarSyrupDataStream, I get an error message "No Extension Exists for pmml:predict"

The [WSO2 Siddhi Gpl Execution Pmml](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml/#how-to-use) document says to copy the component [jar](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml/releases) file to the `<STREAM_PROCESSOR_HOME>/lib` direcotry. The problem is, none of the tar or zip files has a jar file. They all contain pom.xml files and none of the documentation I've found has told me where to deploy the extension.

I tried deploying it in the library directory referenced above and in the features and plug-ins directories as well.  I stop and restart the Stream Processor Studio service (editor.sh) each time. Always I get the same error message.

I have installed the WSO2 product on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and access the stream processor studio through a Firefox browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **siddhi-gpl-excecution-pmml** is released under [General Public License](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml/license/), it's not shipped with the WSO2 Stream Processor which is released under Apache 2 license.

Therefore you need to manually add such jars to WSO2 Stream Processor.

However it's not hosted in the git. You can find the [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/gpl/execution/pmml/siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml/4.0.11/siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml-4.0.11.jar) for the **siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml** extension in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.pmml/siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml).

Also after you copy that jar to /lib directory, please restart the server. The extension will get deployed. No need to add it to the features or pluggins.

Best Regards!

Comment: Thanks.  I used the Jar you provided and am no longer getting the error message.

Comment: You can find it's jar in the following location.
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/gpl/execution/streamingml/siddhi-gpl-execution-streamingml/1.0.12/siddhi-gpl-execution-streamingml-1.0.12.jar

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't think anyone had responded so I deleted the comment. I eventually figured out how to compile and package it in Maven to create the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Now all the siddhi extensions are available in the [WSO2 Extensions Store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/analyticsextension/list). You can download the jar of the extension you need from there.