# WSO2 SP fails to use PMML file to make predictions

Tags: wso2, siddhi, pmml, wso2-streaming-integrator

Following the examples presented in the WSO2 SP 4.1.0 documentation, I am trying to run an example where I read data from a csv file, I predict some result based on the data, and the export the predicted result to a csv file.

So far, the reading and writing to a csv file is working fine, but when I add the PMML prediction part, I cant run the file getting as error "ERROR {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.pmml.util.PMMLUtil} - Failed to unmarshal the pmml definition: null".

The model is a random forest regressor with 15 trees and max_depth=15 trained with sklearn and was exported using the sklearn2pmml 0.35.1 Python library.
I already copied the "siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml-4.0.13.jar" file to "{wso2_4.0.0 install dir}/lib".

I am wondering if there is a version mismatch between the PMML definition exported with sklearn2pmml (the model follows the PMML 4.3 definition) and the PMML definitions accepted by WSO2 SP.

EDIT:

The error isnt showing right now, and I am attaching an image of the WSO2 SP Editor running on Firefox where you can see that the query has an error, but the error box is empty! (this only happens with this error).

[Link to a screenshot. Note that the message box from the error is empty!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dISij.png)

EDIT2:

I already tried the .jar proposed in [No Extension Exists for pmml:predict WSO2 Stream Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48530982/no-extension-exists-for-pmmlpredict-wso2-stream-processor?rq=1) (siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml-4.0.11.jar) and also the siddhi-gpl-execution-pmml-4.0.13.jar. Both give the same error (without any explanation in the error message box).

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 SP's PMML extension supports PMML 4.3 definitions inherently.

Can you please verify the "pmml_model_path" provided as the parameter for the extension.

Comment: The path is correct. This is how I am using the predict statement: `from InputStream#pmml:predict('/home/i2g/MLTest/randomforest.pmml') select * insert into OutputStream;`

Comment: Can you attach the full stacktrace

Comment: You mean, the terminal output?

Comment: Can you copy the siddhi file into the <SP_HOME>/deployment/siddhi-files and start the worker. (run ./worker.sh on <SP_HOME>/bin).

Then attach the errors you see on the backend console.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved it. The problem was the variable type definition (one variable was defined as double in the PMML and as float in the siddhi file).